# Suppose a is a group element such that $|a^{28}|=10$ and $|a^{22}|=20$. Determine |a|.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

|a| is the order of a.

I let |a| = n. Then since $(a^{28})^{10}$ = e, n|280 and since $(a^{22})^{20}$ = e, n|440.

Therefore, n|gcd(280, 440). Thus the possible values of n are 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 40.

Since $a^{28}$ $\neq$ e, then n cannot be 1, 2, or 4. If |a| = 5, then $(a^5)^{28} = e = (a^{28})^5$, which cannot be true since $|a^{28}|$ = 10. Similarly, I am able to argue that n $\neq$ 10 and n $\neq$ 8. I am having trouble arguing that n $\neq$ 20. How can I do this?

Comment: By $\vert a \vert$, do you mean the order of $a$?

Comment: Yes order of a.

Comment: If $|a| = n$ then $|a^x| = n / \gcd(n,x)$ if I'm not mistaken. Substituting $n = 20$ and $x = 28$ leads to $|a^{28}| = 5$ instead of $10$.

Answer (score 5):

If $ n $ were equal to $ 20 $, then $ (a^{28})^5 = a^{140} = (a^{20})^7=e $, so $ a^{28} $ would not have order $ 10 $.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d=n\wedge 28$, $d'=n\wedge 22$. We have $\dfrac nd=10$, $\dfrac n{d'}=20$n so 
$$n=10d=20d'n \quad\text{whence}\quad d=2d'.$$
On the other hand, $d$ is a divisor of $28$, and above shows $d'$ is, too. As it is also a divisor of $22$, the only possibilities are $d'=1$, $d'=2$, corresponding to $d=2$, $d=4$.

However, if $d=2$, $n=20$, and $20\wedge 28=4$, not $2$. So the only solution is $d=4$, and $n=40$.